# bootstrap modal prevent rightclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I try to preventDefault on mouse-rightclick and it works fine until I try to open a bootstrap modal.

If I use "alert" og do nothing the rightclick is prevented, but when I open a bootstrap modal it is not. I've tried to google it, but I can't find my answer.

```
    $(".timer").on("contextmenu", function(evt) {evt.preventDefault();});

    $(".timer").mousedown(function(e){
        // $(".timer").bind('contextmenu', function(){ return false });
        e.preventDefault();

        if( e.button == 2 ) { 
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#changeTime').modal('show'); // rightclick is NOT prevented.
            // alert('Hello'); // this works...?
            return false; 
        } 
        return true; 
    });
```

Can anyone please help me? Thanks.

The php is:

```
    echo '<td class="description" name="id' . $todos->id . '">
    <span class="descriptionText'.$todos->id.'">'
     . $todos->description . '</span></td><td style="width:50px;">
     <span class="timer pull-right btn btn-primary" name="id'.$todos->id.'">
     ' . show_time($todos->total_time) . '</span></td></tr>';
```

The HTML modal is:

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="changeTime" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Change time</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
                <form>
                    // A lot of HTML :)
                </form>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: In the modal do you have an `iframe`?

Comment: No, it is not in an iframe. And I have no iframes on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So based on the comments below, I think I should update my answer.

You wanted to ignore a default click and allow a modal to show up using the right click instead.

In order for that to happen, you need to block all of the things that a default click would do using `preventDefault()` and `stopPropagation()`

```
$("[data-toggle='modal']").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

After that you want to bind the modal opening function to the right click event, but don't show the context menu.

```
$("[data-toggle='modal']").on("contextmenu", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // don't show the context menu
    $("#changeTime").modal("show"); // show the modal window
})
```

[Here's a CodePen of it working](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GiqKp)

Comment: Please read the first line of my code, it is exactly the same. It works fint I know, but if I try to open a bootstrap modal, the rightclick is not prevented. The only difference is that you use a ID, but that is not an option for what I am trying to do. But thank you for your answer :)

Comment: @BrianBak Wow, thanks for pointing that out.  Maybe I've misunderstood the question then.  Could you provide some HTML in context for me to look at?

Comment: I have edited my question, but I am not sure that will help you, it's a very typical modal. Thank you for trying :)

Comment: Thank you for posting the HTML, but I can't seem to find a `.timer` element.  Would that be something in the "// A lot of HTML :)" area?

Comment: I don't think that is the problem, but I have edited the question again :)

Comment: I've edited my answer, is that more of what you're looking for?

Comment: I am so sorry, I thank you for trying, but what I am trying to do is to prevent the rightclick on a element ( like your button ), but show the modal if rightclick is pressed. This works every time if it's not a bootstrap modal I try to open. I try to open the modal with a rightclick, but I can't prevent the deafult windows action.

Comment: @BrianBak last attempt, and I think I've got what you're looking for. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GiqKp -- tell me if that works for you.

Comment: You got it!!! Thank you VERY much :) I did not know stopPropagation. Thank you again, that was very kind of you.

Comment: I just tested it on my system and it works :D Thank you SO much! :)